# UnboundLocalError: local variable 't_min' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, telebot

```
def process_select_step(message):
    try:
        if (message.text == 'Погода'):
            msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Выберите город (например Москва)")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, next_weather_step)
        else:
            send_welcome(message)

    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'ooops!')
        print(e)

def next_weather_step(message):
    town = message.text
    weather(message, towns=town)


# Погода
def weather(message,towns):
    r = requests.get('https://sinoptik.ua/погода-{0}'.format(towns))
    html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

    for el in html.select('#content'):
        t_min = el.select('.temperature .min')[0].text
        print(t_min)
        t_max = el.select('.temperature .max')[0].text
        print(t_max)
        text = el.select('.wDescription .description')[0].text
        print(text)
    # убрать клавиатуру
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, погода на сегодня:\n",reply_markup=markup)
```

> 2020-05-27 16:26:00,818 (util.py:68 WorkerThread2) ERROR - TeleBot:
>   "UnboundLocalError occurred, args=("local variable 't_min' referenced
>   before assignment",) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Telebot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py",
>   line 62, in run
>       task(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Telebot/main.py", line 34, in
>   next_weather_step
>       weather(message, towns=town)   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Telebot/main.py", line 50, in weather
>       t_min + ', ' + t_max + '\n' + text, reply_markup=markup) UnboundLocalError: local variable 't_min' referenced before assignment

Comment: вы бы не могли указать в коде 50 строку? в коде который вы добавили нет блока который вызывает ошибку

Comment: и непонятно зачем парсить сайт, если можно воспользоваться например openweathermap. Но выбор конечно за Вами